# WCF 4.0 Cookie Only First is Recorded by Browser

Tags: wcf, rest, cookies

I am working on the fastest way to write cookies from a WCF self hosted console app REST service with WebHttpBinding.
I prepare the "Set Cookies" but only the first cookie is set in the browser (using FireFox 11.0 on Windows) as well as the "Expires" value.

```
var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMonths( 6 );
var outresp = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
outresp.Headers.Add( HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie , "cookie1=fd9416ea-2705-4d44-be76-f2f7b95e6b13; cookie2=7d489e69-d9c9-4b8d-a4b1-bce0da1c5966;expires=" + expiry );
```

I also tried putting a comma between the first cookie and the second one, that did not work either:

```
outresp.Headers.Add( HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie , "cookie1=fd9416ea-2705-4d44-be76-f2f7b95e6b13;, cookie2=7d489e69-d9c9-4b8d-a4b1-bce0da1c5966;expires=" + expiry );
```

I cut this down, and fired up Fiddler:

```
outresp.Headers.Add( HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie , "foo=foovalue;,bar=barvalue;" );
```

and Fiddler shows this:

```
Response sent 27 bytes of Cookie data:
    Set-Cookie: foo=foovalue;,bar=barvalue;

This response did not contain a P3P Header.

Validate P3P Policies at: http://www.w3.org/P3P/validator.html
Learn more at: http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=p3pinfo
```

Which tells me that I am not formatting things on the .NET side to make the cookies acceptable to the browser.

How can I get all of the cookies into the browser insetad of just the first value? What did I miss?

Thanks.

[ EDIT ]

I took the issue to Microsoft for support, and learned this:

The fact that "Set-Cookie" is munged into a single cookie line is logged as a bug within Microsoft for .NET Framework 4.0 and also Framework 4.5. 
Within the Microsoft WCF development group, the bug is listed as "closed" and "won't fix".
According to Microsoft, the only workaround is to move from self-hosted to hosting within IIS and then using the (IIS) Response object directly (different code path that does not have the bug).

Comment: Providing service config, service interface, service class attributes and method attributes could be helpful.

Comment: Also, include your host config and code.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an older post, since this is still an ongoing issue and using the AspNetCompatibilityMode with WCF has significant performance downside, the option that MSFT has supplied is not viable under many/most/any circumstances.  I'm going to answer this question late since this issue is still lingering.

The only way to  resolve this issue is to output the Set-Cookie response header just as you've shown, but to process that response header on the client side with javascript and place it in to the browser since, as you've noted, the browser will not handle this response.  Neither will applying more than one Set-Cookie response header work as noted in this bug I created.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779111/wcf-rest-service-two-set-cookie-http-headers-invalid-set-cookie-header-syntax

So, process the response header and use document.cookie in client-side javascript to place the cookies in the browser within the success handler of your jQuery .ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @jeff-fischer 's answer, AspNetCompatibilityMode does work and requires the following:

`AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` is set for the service class to either `Allowed` or `Required` e.g.:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
       = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class AppService : IAppService
```

`<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />` is set in `<system.serviceModel>`

This then gives access to `HttpContext` (you'll need `using System.Web;` to get access to this) and cookies can be set using:

```
var aCookie = new HttpCookie("foo")
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Value = "bar",
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
};

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

This will then need to be run as an application on IIS rather than though the WCF launcher and if multiple cookies are set, multiple cookie headers will actually appear.