# Adding multiple Set-Cookie Headers in ASP.NET Web

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I faced a problem.

When you add multiple **Set-Cookie** headers to the response

```
headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "a=b;Path=/;");
headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "c=d;Path=/;");
```

actually they are combined and only one header is sent with comma-separated  cookies

```
Set-Cookie: a=b;Path=/;,c=d;Path=/;
```

According to [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) it is a valid syntax.
But it is not according to [RFC6265](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt), which deprecates **RFC2109**

Moreover latest browsers does not support this comma-separated syntax as well. Tested on **IE9**, **Firefox 13** and **Google Chrome 20**.

All of these browsers took first cookie only.

Please see the sample project below

https://github.com/mnaoumov/cookie-bug/

I want to find some workaround.

I expect to have two different **Set-Cookie** headers.

I tried to write some **MessageInspector** to rewrite HTTP headers. I could not find how to access that headers.

Any ideas?

P.S. Used technology: Web API

Comment: Raised a bug on __codeplex__.
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/288

Comment: Just FYI, here's the bit that prohibits comma separated cookies under a single header: "_An origin server can include multiple Set-Cookie header fields in a single response.  … Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into a single header field._" - from [RFC 6265 - HTTP State Management Mechanism (overview section)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to answer on **codeplex** (http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/288) this issue is known issue and related to WCF self-hosting and should be fixed by moving to IIS hosting.

This is WCF 4 issue which marked as **won't fix**.

Found another question with the same outcome [WCF 4.0 Cookie Only First is Recorded by Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221211/wcf-4-0-cookie-only-first-is-recorded-by-browser/11706532).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie

```
using System.Web;


HttpCookie foo = new HttpCookie("foo", "true");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(foo); 

HttpCookie bar = new HttpCookie("bar", "true");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(bar);
```

This will add multiple set-cookies header in the response.

Edit: also, you should add the

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

in your web.config