# Can´t set cookies | SET-cookie header correctly

Tags: php, cookies

I can´t set cookies with setcookie().

I thought it´s really easy to set cookies with this, but it won´t work...

What I found was this: Something to add cookies in a header with "set-cookies". This should solve my problem (I guess, didn´t try by now).

[Set-Cookie Header With Multiple Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533867/set-cookie-header-with-multiple-cookies)

The next problem: How to add multible headers for cookies correctly?

In the php manual I didn´t find anything for this (or even set-cookie header).

Anyone got a solution for this?

this is what i got by now, but the browser won´t accept my cookies (returns false when I test it)

```
setcookie('testCookie','testValue',time()+31536000,'/','www.mydomain.com');
```

Comment: Is your setcookie() function located before any text output? (echo, error display, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `setcookie` **before** any content is outputted to the page (e.g. `echo` or `print` statements).

Comment: a common bug is saving the source file with the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) symbol