# Asynchronous login tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I used Tornado to create a login page which works on synchronous method.Now I want to make it asynchronous. So what are the changes I should do to the following code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import http
import time

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect("/login")
            return
        name = tornado.escape.xhtml_escape(self.current_user)
        self.write('<html>'
    '<head> '
    '<title>WELCOME  </title>'
    '</head>'
    '<body style="background:orange;"'

    '<div align="center">'
    '<div style="margin-top:200px;margin-bottom:10px;">'
    '<span style="width:500px;color:black;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;">WELCOME </span>'
    '</div>'
    '<div style="margin-bottom:5px;">'"Hello, " + name)

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
                   '<div><span style="width:100px;;height: 500px;color:black;font-size:60;font-weight:bold;">'
                   'LOGIN'
                   '<div><span style="width:100px;;height: 500px;color:purple;font-size:30;font-weight:bold;">'
                   'NAME <input type="text" name="name">'
                   '<div><span style="width:100px;height: 500px;color:purple;font-size:30;font-weight:bold;">PASSWORD</span><input style="width:150px;" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">'
                   '</div>'                   
                   '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
                   '</form></body></html>')

    def post(self):
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
        time.sleep(10)
        self.redirect("/")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/login", LoginHandler),
], cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__")

application.listen(5000)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

In my code I have three classes `BaseHandler`, `MainHandler` and `LoginHandler`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call "sleep" in a Tornado method:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html

If you want to pause the method for a while to prove to yourself that it's non-blocking, add `from tornado import gen` and try:

```
async def post(self):
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
    yield gen.sleep(10)
    self.redirect("/")
```

Or in Python 2:

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
    yield gen.sleep(10)
    self.redirect("/")
```

Comment: I get the following error , when i try yield gen.sleep:                           raise BadYieldError("yielded unknown object %r" % (yielded,))
tornado.gen.BadYieldError: yielded unknown object <async_generator object LoginHandler.post at 0x035A85F0>
ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /login (::1) 8.00ms

Comment: Is there a way to make this code async. by changing the func. and by using                                                                                        '@return_future
def future_func(arg1, arg2, callback):
    # Do stuff (possibly asynchronous)
    callback(result)
@gen.engine
def caller(callback):
    yield future_func(arg1, arg2)
    callback()

Answer (score 1):

#### A simple example

Python 3.5 introduced the `async` and `await` keywords (functions using these keywords are also called “native coroutines”). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090798/13155046) for more details.

Every class-based view we construct for our Tornado app must inherit from the `RequestHandler` object found in `tornado.web`.

If we override the `prepare` method, we can set some logic to run that'll do whenever a `request` is received.

`def tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_current_user(self)` - Override to determine the current user from, e.g., a cookie.

A subclass may override `get_current_user()`, which will be called automatically the first time `self.current_user` is accessed. `get_current_user()` will only be called once per request, and is cached for future access.

```py
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        if self.get_argument("btn1", None) is not None:
            print("detected click on btn Profile")
            self.redirect("/profile")
            return

        if self.get_argument("btn2", None) is not None:
            print("detected click on btn Sources")
            self.redirect("/sources")
            return

        if self.get_argument("logout", None) is not None:
            self.clear_cookie("username")
            self.redirect("/")
            return

        if self.get_argument("btnSignIn", None) is not None:
            print("detected click on btnSignIn")
            self.redirect("/signin")
            return

    def get_current_user(self):
        a = self.get_secure_cookie("username")
        if a:
            return a.decode("utf-8")
        return None
```

```py
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('login.html')

    def prepare(self):
        super().prepare()

    async def post(self):
        username = self.get_argument("username")
        password = self.get_argument("password")

        my_db = self.settings['db']
        collection = my_db.test

        val = await do_check_one(collection, username, password)

        if val is not None:
            self.set_secure_cookie("username", username)
            self.redirect("/profile")
        else:
            self.write('<h1>Wrong credentials</h1>')
```

For a better understanding see: [Simplest async/await example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64508472/13155046).

```py
async def do_check_one(my_collection, value1, value2):
    document = await my_collection.find_one({"name": value1, "password": value2})
    return document
```

and `main`:

Options must be defined with `tornado.options.define` before use, generally at the top level of a module. The options are then accessible as attributes of `tornado.options.options`.

The `main()` method of your application does not need to be aware of all of the options used throughout your program; they are all automatically loaded when the modules are loaded. However, all modules that define options must have been imported before the command line is parsed.

```py
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client.test
    collection = db.test

    settings = {
        "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        "cookie_secret": "_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
        "login_url": "/login",
        "db": db,
        "debug": True,
        "xsrf_cookies": True
    }

    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers=[(r'/', MainHandler),
                  (r'/sources', SourceHandler),
                  (r'/login', LoginHandler),
                  (r'/signin', SigninHandler),
                  (r'/profile', ProfileHandler),
                  (r'/favicon.ico', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings['static_path'])),
                  ],
        **settings
    )
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
        print('Server started...')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Server has shut down.')
```

Your `main()` method can parse the command line or parse a config file with either `parse_command_line` or `parse_config_file`:

```py
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
# or
tornado.options.parse_config_file("/etc/server.conf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `async/await` notation here, possibly adapt to fit your Python version:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get_current_user(self):
        return await some_async_operation()

    async def prepare(self):
        self.current_user = await self.get_current_user()
```

Tornado won't call `get_current_user` asynchronously out of the box, but it will honour asynchronous `prepare` methods, so you can populate `self.current_user` there.

Comment: Thank you for helping.But I get an error :500 when I execute the code.

Comment: You'll have to check your error logs/activate debugging here, 500 could be a lot of things.

Comment: oh ok, So the above mentioned changes should ideally make the code work asynchronously.Is that right?

Comment: Yes. In your code within `def get` etc. you just use `self.current_user`; the only place asynchronicity is relevant is how `self.current_user` is being populated, and that simply happens in `prepare` (overriding the default Tornado implementation of how `self.current_user` is populated). There *may* of course be some error being triggered here, but you need to investigate that in detail.

Comment: Isn't it necessary to add the keyword async before every def function?

Comment: *If* you're doing any `await` within it, yes.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is, or it has been answered…?

Comment: My question is that my code works synchronously, but to make it asynchronous ,what changes should be done in the code ?

Comment: What I'm showing above is how you can make the resolution of `current_user` asynchronous; I was under the impression that was the stumbling block. If that's not all you'll need to clarify what exactly it is you want to make asynchronous.

Comment: That is exactly what I want;to make the current_user asynchronous.Thank you for your help.Let me now figure out the reason for  Error:500

Comment: Run Tornado in debug mode to get a stack trace. http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#debug-mode-and-automatic-reloading

Comment:  Well, obviously you're supposed to substitute *your* code there to determine the current user.